# how to scrape the second part in html / AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to **scrape** the word "bla" from HTML but it gives me nothing. How to get it?

```
<span id="Row1Field154" fieldalias="MajorityRequired">bla</span>


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import request
html = urlopen("Url")
#print(html.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser")
result=soup.find("span", {"id":"Row1Field154"})
print(result)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your url if this public and mentioned whats your expected output as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print(result.text)`

Note: You have a mistake in ID. Row**1**Field154 vs Row**0**Field154.

Comment: I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'. I have a list of ids...@Alexander Chzhen

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

```
html_cod = '''<span id="Row1Field154" fieldalias="MajorityRequired">bla</span>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib import request
# html = urlopen("url")
#print(html.read())
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_cod,"html.parser")
result=soup.find("span", {"id":"Row1Field154"})
print(result.text)
```

Output: `bla`

Comment: Thank you but I need to get it from the URL /: @Humayun Ahmad Rajib

Comment: Please share your `URL`

Comment: @ddd You have to find out where you problem begins. Put print at every step in order to see what is happening.